# Spring MVC and JSP framework

Tags: jsp, frameworks

What is a very good jsp framework to use with Spring MVC.
Are the only candidates SiteMesh and Tiles, and others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Tapestry yet?
http://tapestry.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh) and [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org) are other good options.